# Mockito - Interface method is called when I need it to call the implementation class

Tags: java, mockito

I have an interface

```
public abstract interface SomeSetRemote
  extends Remote
{

    public abstract someMethod getMedata(int paramInt)
        throws  RemoteException;
}
```

**Implementation class**

```
public class SomeSet
  extends Remote
{

    public someMethod getMedata(int paramInt)
        throws  RemoteException
    {
        System.Out.println(" Hi I am a class..........);
    }

}
```

Question is there is a call in the method I am testing which returns the interface and subsequently there is a method call which is not working because it is trying it on the interface.

So, the method call is like this

```
someObject.getSomeSet().getMedata()
```

`someObject.getSomeSet()` returns the interface so the implementation class `getMedata` is not called.

How do I make Mockito to call the implementation class method?

This is legacy code so unable to change it.

Thanks

Comment: How are you creating your mock or spy?

Comment: Spy, want the actual method to execute.

Comment: Can you show us how you're creating your spy?

Comment: So, SomeOtherObject myWO = Mockito.spy( new SomeOtherObject((SomeSet) someSet)); On this I am calling a method, call it testingMethod, within that method there is this someObject.getSomeSet().getMedata(), where someObject.getSomeSet() is returning an interface which I am not able to intercept or handle.

Comment: So you've got your spy, `myWO`, and you've got a different object, `someObject`.  And your test is calling the methods on `someObject`, instead of on `myWO`, right?

Comment: no, it is calling a method in myWO, within that method there is this someObject.getSomeSet() which is returning a interface remote object (RMI). In isolation this interface is not able to service getMedata method. This same class once deployed on application server using RMI principles works fine.

Comment: OK, I'm having difficulty following what you're saying.  This would be much easier if you could POST the test code in the question, instead of DESCRIBING what it looks like.

Comment: Please **never** put more infos into comments; **always** update your question instead.

Comment: And I really think you want to provide a [mcve] here. I have no idea what your real problem is.

Answer (score 2):

As you know the issue is at `someObject.getSomeSet()` returning the interface. Then try to mock that:

```
Remote remoteObj = new SomeSet();
when(someObject.getSomeSet()).thenReturn(remoteObj);
```

From here, You can call using `remoteObj`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But this someObject.getSomeSet().getMedata() is within a method which I am unit testing. So, I am testing a method in a totally third class, which has this line and I am stumped.

Comment: It needs to be seen how the SomeSet object is initialiazed in the testing method. Please pdate the question with the code of that "totally third class".